# WordPress .htaccess rewrite not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there anything wrong with this rule, it's for a WordPress site.

I have the non friendly URL:

```
/listing/?category=Cocktail+Bars
```

I would like to to be written as:

```
/london/cocktail-bars
```

This is my rule:

```
RewriteRule ^london/cocktail-bars$ /listing/?category=Cocktail+Bars [QSA,L]
```

Here is the complete `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^london/cocktail-bars$ /listing/?category=Cocktail+Bars [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I fixed it, the index.php was missing :)

```
RewriteRule ^london/cocktail-bars$ /index.php/listing/?category=Cocktail+Bars [QSA,L]
```